# C : Typecasting output of atoi() to unsigned char?

Tags: c++, casting, std, atoi

I've boiled down the issue to a typecasting problem from atoi()'s output. Basically, I pass a string.c_str() to atoi(), and I can 'cout' the value just as I'd expect (32). However, if I do a typecast like this:

```
string num = "32";
unsigned char x = (unsigned char)atoi(num.c_str());
cout << x << endl;
```

Then x ends up not having ANY value. It's not just 0 or something, but NULL. What gives?

Comment: How have you determined that x has no value?

Comment: Okay. `#include <bitset>` and do this: `cout << bitset<8>(x);` to see the actual 8 bit binary representation of `x` to confirm its really 0.

Comment: Try `cout << (long)x << endl;` - it should print `32`.

Answer (score 3):

`char` represents character symbols. When you print it via stream you will see ASCII char. 32 is code of a `space` symbol in ASCII code, thats why you dont see anything.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` value represents a character, so printing it character to a stream displays the character itself, not its numeric code.

If the numeric value of the character you're printing is represented by a printable ASCII letter, such as the value 65 corresponding to the letter `A`, you'll see the letter displayed in console/terminal output. In your example, the numeric code is 32, which corresponds to space, which will remain invisible. Numeric code 0 would result in some representation of the binary NUL character being printed by your terminal.